# Comentários Obsoletos

Tags: suporte, comunidade, comentários

Gostaria de saber o que fazer quando nos deparamos como uma pergunta assim:

[Erro na porta serial do arduino com comunicação entre C e Perl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148627/4816)

Ela possui uma grande quantidade de comentários que podem ser considerados "obsoletos" - ela já foi fechada, reaberta e solucionada, e eu sei que manter o SOpt "limpo" é um desejo comum.

> - Damos flag em todos os comentários obsoletos?
> - Damos flag em apenas um? (um moderador verá os outros de qualquer jeito)
> - Não damos flag em nenhum/deixamos como está? :'(

Comment: Regra geral há uma flag/sinalizador para comentários obsoletos. Neste caso era bom a resposta ser colocada como resposta e depois então limpar os comentários.

Comment: Eu sempre dou _flag_ **em todos** que eu acho obsoleto. Até hoje ninguém reclamou pra mim, então acho que é o certo

Comment: Depende de caso para caso, se tiver alguns comentários no meio de vários que acha que precisam ser apagados pode sinalizar de um em um para que fique mais fácil pros mods identificarem quais são, se quiser que remova todos e forem muitos pode sinalizar um só com uma mensagem customizada dizendo que é para apagar todos. Nesse caso sinalizar de um em um também não tá errado, só que é mais trabalhoso

Comment: Sobre esse caso em específico também acho importante que a resposta seja postada antes que se apague a maioria dos comentários

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com as orientações nos outros sites da [rede](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254854/460775), você tem algumas opções:

1. Se forem poucos, sinalize separadamente os comentários. Se um comentário foi sinalizado mais de uma vez, ele pode ser automaticamente [removido](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156128/155051).
2. Se forem muitos, por exemplo toda uma conversa, você pode sinalizar a pergunta/resposta e descrever que toda a conversa é obsoleta e pode ser deletada. Sinalizar o post ao invés do comentário pode ser mais útil já que permite usar outras [ferramentas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254853/flagging-a-whole-comment-thread-as-obsolete#comment21141_254854)

Para conseguir um efeito que ajude outros a longo prazo, você pode deixar um comentário conforme dito [neste post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261956/155051).

Comment: Eu acho mais eficiente sinalizar um a um, apesar do trabalho, reduz a possibilidade de apagar um comentário que afeta o contexto do que é relevante permanecer e facilita a resolução por parte do moderador.

Comment: @diegofm como disse, se for remover **toda uma conversa**, os moderadores tem acesso a uma ferramenta que remove todos os comentários. Neste caso, é justamente pra facilitar pro moderador. Note que foi um moderador que sugeriu isso (3 link do meu post).